# Vim "Follows" Hard links

Tags: vimrc, git, plugin-fugitive

I have a git repository that contains my vimrc file and a couple of other utilities, called `myvimrcgit`. I then hard link my vimrc to `~/.vimrc`, so that they point to the same inodes. Now, when I go to vim and command `edit ~/myvimrcgit/vimrc`, the buffer actually loads the `~/.vimrc` file. Running `:echo expand("%")` also yields the filename as `~/.vimrc`. This is a problem when I want to use Fugitive to do some git operations while editing my vimrc since Fugitive relies on the filename rather than the current working directory. Calling edit on the original vimrc (`edit ~/.vimrc`) yields the normal `~/.vimrc` file.

Any tips on how to disable this functionality and why does vim always resolve filenames this way?

Comment: The same scenario with  hardlinks done outside of Fugitive context has a different result?

Comment: @BLayer I did the same operation with `~/wow` and `~/Documents/wow` being linked, and the same thing is happening but now it always resolves to `~/Documents/wow` no matter if I open the first or the second file.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on either vim 8.1.998 or nvim 0.3.3. That said, either of those *does* recognize within the context of a single session. It basically goes by the first name you access it by in a given session.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea, generally speaking, since AFAIK git doesn't even honor hardlinks.

Comment: Like EdGrimm I also see behavior where whatever path I open the hardlinked file with remains in Vim even if I try to open it by a different path to the file (in the same session). But you're not seeing this behavior? Regardless of how you open it always goes by the homedir path? That doesn't sound right. Unless it differs by OS... (I only tried with Cygwin/Win10).

Comment: @BLayer It seems like this happens if the buffer is not completely unloaded. If you load the alternate name, it still creates a new buffer but with the filename of the previously opened file.